# Error handling while reading file in C

Tags: c, file, error-handling

I'm finishing my C implementation of Conway's Game of Life, and I have a problem with error handling when parsing incorrect netting file.

File format is:

```
rows cols
x1   y1
x2   y2
```

Reading function:

```
net_t *file_to_net( net_t *n, char *filename )
{
assert( n != NULL );

FILE *f = fopen( filename, "r" );
if( f == NULL )
    print_error_file( filename );

if( fscanf( f, "%d %d", &(n->rows), &(n->cols) ) != 2 )
    print_error("net");

n->vec = calloc( n->rows * n->cols, sizeof(unsigned char) );
if( n->vec == NULL )
    print_error("alloc");

int i, x, y;
while( fscanf( f, "%d %d", &x, &y ) == 2 )
{
    if( x > n->rows || y > n->cols )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "%sERROR:%s Coordinates of living cell in net file is bigger then net dimensions.\n", COLOR_RED, COLOR_RESET );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    i = ( n->cols * (x - 1) ) + (y - 1);
    n->vec[i] = 1;
}
if( !feof(f) )
    print_error("net");

fclose(f);

return n;
}
```

Error handling works when there are letters instead of digits (while loop ends, but not EOF), but it doesn't work when I don't have one of the coordinates (there is an odd number of numbers), for example:

```
50 50
2 3
3 4
4
4 3
4 4
```

does not end with error.
I've been trying to implement it, but I can't make it work in all 3 cases (good file, non-digits inside and odd number of numbers).

---

EDIT

OK, thanks very much for the help. Ended with this code of the loop, which covers all three cases:

```
int i, x, y;
int pos;
while( fgets( line, MAXL, f ) != NULL )
{
    if( sscanf( line, "%d %d %n", &x, &y, &pos ) != 2 )
    {
        print_error("net");
    }
    else if( line[pos] != '\0' )
    {
        print_error("net");
    }


    if( x > n->rows || y > n->cols )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "%sERROR:%s Coordinates of living cell in net file is bigger then net dimensions.\n", COLOR_RED, COLOR_RESET );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    i = ( n->cols * (x - 1) ) + (y - 1);
    n->vec[i] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Because the space in `scanf()` doesn't only match the `' '`, but **any** whitespace character (i. e. ` \t\n\r\f'). Don't use `scanf()`, inconvenient, subtle quirks like this make it a nightmare to use. Call `fgets()` instead to read the file line by line, then parse the line with something like `strchr()`, `strstr()`, `strpbrk()` or the like.

Comment: @user3477950 Yeah, I know why it's like that, but I don't know how to make it see that when fscanf doeasn't read two files and it's not end of file it should print error. I'll look into `fgets` then, but can it be done with `fscanf`?

Comment: @pawel.ad I don't think so, not in the current form. You would need some other kind of line or column separator (in order scanf to be able to decide whether or not it was able to read an entire line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace:

```
while( fscanf( f, "%d %d", &x, &y ) == 2 )
```

with:

```
int rc;

while ((rc = fscanf(f, "%d %d", &x, &y)) == 2)
{
    …
}

if (rc == EOF)
    …report EOF…
else
    …report format error…
```

The `else` clause can be triggered because of non-numeric data in the file, or because there was a number missing somewhere.  Note that `scanf()` won't care if there are 50 space-separated numbers on a single line, nor if there are 20 blank lines between each separate coordinate, or any hybrid mess of a layout.

If you want to read by lines and report, you probably want to use some of the ideas from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23035070/15168) by [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109), plus some extra tweaks:

```
char line[4096];
int rc;
int pos;

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
{
    if ((rc = sscanf(line, "%d %d %n", &x, &y, &pos)) != 2)
    {
        …analyze for EOF or format error…
    }
    else if (line[pos] != '\0')
    {
        …trailing non-blank junk on line…
    }
    else
    {
        …all clean and tidy…
    }
}
```

Note that `%n` conversion specifications are not counted in the results (hence the check is still 2, not 3).  Also, the space before the `%n` is OK in `sscanf()`, but would be horrendous for interactive input (the input would not end until the user typed some non-white space character).  These sorts of subtle details are why the `scanf()` family of functions are something of a nightmare for beginners (heck — they don't make it easy for experienced programmers either).

Comment: I was trying to add some kind of `\n` at the end of `scanf` but it didin't help, but this works - thanks!

Comment: Getting `scanf()` to recognize `\n` is hard.  Note that any white space in a format string means 'zero or more white space characters', so embedding a newline in the string simply means 'gobble white space until you get to a non-white space character'.  This is nasty behaviour for interactive I/O — hence my notes about the space and `sscanf()` being OK (by definition, the input is not interactive when it comes from a string).

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, `fscanf` treats newline characters as if they were spaces, so it has no concept of lines.  If you put one number on a line, `fscanf` will read that number, and then get the second number from the next line.  An easy solution to this problem is to use `fgets` to read lines from  the file and use `sscanf` to extract the numbers from each line.  That doesn't detect all errors, (for example it won't detect three numbers on a line), but it's a little better than what you have.  For stringent error checking, you could read lines with `fgets`, and then break the line into tokens with `strtok` and then verify that each token is a valid number by writing your own string-to-number conversion algorithm.  The built-in conversion routines are notoriously bad at error checking.

Here's a snippet that demonstrates how to use `fgets` with `sscanf`

```
#define MAXL 1024
static char line[MAXL];

    while ( fgets( line, MAXL, stdin ) != NULL )
    {
        if ( sscanf( line, "%d %d", &x, &y ) != 2 )
        {
            fprintf( ... );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        ...

    }
```

Comment: I implemented it, but now it parses `3 4as` line as valid and reads `3` and `4` - any idea why?

Comment: "The built-in conversion routines are notoriously bad at error checking."  From the man page for `sscanf`: "Scanning stops when an input character does not match such a format character." In other words, `a` can't be part of the second number, so `sscanf` just stops at that point.  If you want stringent error checking, you'll have to write your own conversion routines.